# Нахождение наибольшего элемента в матрице, который встречается больше одного раза

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм

Собственно нужно найти наибольший элемент в матрице, который встречается > 1 раза.   Помогите, пожалуйста, с алгоритмом.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int matrix[10][10];

    srand(time(0));

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = rand() % 50; // заполняем
        }
    }
    set <int> myset;
    set <int>::iterator it;
    bool dupFound = false;
    int     maxValue;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            int v = matrix[i][j];
            if (dupFound && v <= maxValue) continue;
            it = myset.find(v);
            if(it == myset.end()) 
                myset.insert(v);
            else {
                maxValue = v;
                if(!dupFound) dupFound = true;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) cout << setw(2) << matrix[i][j] << ' ';
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << maxValue << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#define SIZE 100

int array[SIZE];

bool have_such_number(int idx)
{
    int n = array[idx];
    for( ++idx; idx < SIZE; ++idx ) {
        if( array[idx] == n ) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int get_duplicated_maximum(void)
{
    int max = INT_MIN;
    for( int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i ) {
        if( array[i] > max && have_such_number(i) ) {
            max = array[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  int matrix[10][10];

  srand(time(0));

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
      matrix[i][j] = rand() % 50; // заполняем
    }
  }

  int max = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
      if (matrix[i][j] > max)
        max = matrix[i][j]; // находим наибольшее
    }
  }

  int count = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
      if (matrix[i][j] == max)
        count++; // подсчитываем
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
      cout << matrix[i][j] << "_"; // выводим
    }
  }

  cout << endl << endl;

  if (count > 1){
    cout << "max digit:" << max << " count:" << count << endl; // выводим
  }

  return 0;
}
```

--------------------------переписано позднее

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  int matrix[10][10];
  vector<int> v;

  srand(time(0));

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
      matrix[i][j] = rand() % 50; // заполняем
    }
  }

  int max = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
      for (int a = i + 1; a < 10; a++){
        for (int b = j + 1; b < 10; b++){
          if (matrix[i][j] == matrix[a][b])
            v.push_back(matrix[i][j]);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
      cout << matrix[i][j] << "_"; // выводим матрицу
    }
  }

  cout << endl << "_______________________" << endl;

  for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
    cout << v[i] << "_"; // выводим вектор
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < v.size(); j++){
      if ((v[i] > v[j]) && (v[i] > max)){
        max = v[i]; // находим наибольшее
      }
    }
  }

  cout << endl << "max:" << max << endl; // ответ

  return 0;
}
```

-------------------добавлено позднее

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  int matrix[10][10]; // = { 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
  vector<int> v;

  srand(time(0));

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
      matrix[i][j] = rand() % 50; // заполняем
    }
  }

  int max = 0;//, a = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
      for (int a = i; a < 10; a++){
        for (int b = j + 1; b < 10; b++){
          if (matrix[i][j] == matrix[a][b]){
            v.push_back(matrix[i][j]);
            //break;
          }
        }
        //a++;
      }
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
      cout << matrix[i][j] << "_";
    }
  }

  cout << endl << "_______________________" << endl;

  for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
    cout << v[i] << "_";
  }

  if (v.size() != 0){ 
    max = v[0];
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < v.size(); j++){
      if ((v[i] > v[j]) && (v[i] > max)){
        max = v[i];
      }
    }
  }

  if (v.size() != 0){

    cout << endl << "max:" << max << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: В твоем случае получается, что мы по наибольшему элементу самой матрицы проверяем. 
А если будет так:
1 2 3 
0 2 6
В таком случае правильный ответ 2, а не 6. Т.к. 6 встречается один раз, хоть и наибольший элемент в матрице.

Comment: действительно. сорри не уяснил суть вопроса, переписал. коряво правда немного

Comment: Используйте map, где ключ -- значение из матрицы, а значение map -- количество вхождений.

Comment: @perfect, а сами-то потестировать программу (уже переписанную) пробовали?

--

1). Что будет, если **все** ээлементы отрицательные?

2). Представьте матрицу

    2 2 1 ... 1
    1 1 ....  1
    .....
    1 1 ..... 1

т.е. первые два (в нулевой строке) - двойки, а все остальные еденички. IMHO у Вас в `v` они не попадут. 

Идея-то Ваша понятна, поместить в `v` все повторяющиеся элементы, а вот ее реализация хромает.


3)  Зачем продолжать искать повторы (и заносить их в `v`) после первого найденного?

--

IMHO простейший алгоритм это скопировать матрицу, отсортровать ее и найти первый повтор.

Comment: единичкам попадать и не надо двойки больше единиц (ищем максимальное), а если есть отрицательные числа тогда переменную max инициализируем -65535 (если тип int). я этот код запускал раз 10 вроде работает. сказал сразу что код кривой немного. с проверкой кода на то чтоб прекращать цикл как только повтор найден не стал из за усложнения кода, да и расход тактов на проверку тоже увеличится

Comment: @perfect, так двойки-то и не попадут. Посмотрите на Ваши циклы по a и b. 

Разве matrix[0][0] будет сравниваться с matrix[0][1]?

А в качестве начального значения max удобно брать первый элемент массива (тогда никаких проблем с выбором начального значения).

Comment: действительно. переписал